# Transfer method to the function c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++builder-6

I'm using Builder 6.

Have no idea how to fix bugs:

```
[C++ Error] loltimer.cpp(11): E2316 '_fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *)' is not a member of 'TForm1'
[C++ Error] loltimer.cpp(18): E2062 Invalid indirection
```

My .cpp code:

```
// line 11
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
    comboSpell(ComboBox1);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TForm1::comboSpell(TComboBox *combo){
    // line 18
    *combo ->Items->Add("Flash");
    *combo ->Items->Add("Ignite");
    *combo ->Items->Add("Exhaust");
    *combo ->Items->Add("Teleport");
    *combo ->Items->Add("Ghost");
    *combo ->Items->Add("Heal");
    *combo ->Items->Add("Smite");
    *combo ->Items->Add("Barrier");
}
```

My .h code:

```
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent Owner);
    void comboSpell(TComboBox *combo);
```

Comment: The constructor declaration accepts a TComponent, but on definition you accept a pointer to TComponent.

Comment: Those are compiler errors, not bugs. To have a bug your program has to compile first. ;)

Comment: @dandan78 Tell that to a template metaprogrammer. Or a Haskell programmer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [C++ Error] loltimer.cpp(11): E2316 '_fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *)' is not a member of 'TForm1'

The declaration of your `TForm()` constructor is different in your .h and .cpp code, specifically in the `Owner` parameter.  They need to match:

```
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent *Owner);
```

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    ...
}
```

> [C++ Error] loltimer.cpp(18): E2062 Invalid indirection

You are dereferencing the `combo` pointer using the `*` operator and then dereferencing it again with the `->` operator.  That will not work in this case.  You need to either:

1. Use the `->` operator by itself (the typical usage):

   ```
   combo->Items->Add("Flash");
   ```
2. Use the `.` operator instead of the `->` operator (not typical):

   ```
   (*combo).Items->Add("Flash");
   ```

Comment: but combo -> and (*combo). are same, are they?

Comment: Yes, they are effectively the same, and both are valid syntax, which is why I mentioned both.

Answer (score 4):

The header has the parameter as `TComponent` and the .cpp has it as `TComponent *`. You need them to be the same.